# Monitoring GCP Projects with Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have a "Monitor" project in Google Cloud and want it to monitor the metrics of several other projects. On the Cloud Console, I can easily add these projects to the metric scope of my Monitor project. However, I would like to automate this process in Terraform. Does anyone know how?

Comment: Are you looking for that? https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/monitoring_alert_policy else, can you detail what you want to achieve and where you are stuck?

Comment: that's just an alert policy, it does not activate or configure a monitoring project (such as defining the project scope)

Comment: apparently there's no such module yet :| very old ref: github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/2605 and https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/adding-monitoring-scopes-in-google-cloud/28410

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can achieve that using terraform. You need to have a scoping project or a new project which will host your metrics from other projects.

You can then add the projects as monitored project using the below terraform resource :

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/monitoring_monitored_project

Comment: Is there any tutorial of this?

Comment: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/monitoring_dashboard#example-usage---monitoring-dashboard-basic

Answer (score 0):

To add multiple monitored projects to a monitoring project with terraform, use the [google_monitoring_monitored_project](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/monitoring_monitored_project) resource.

Use the below syntax derived from this post:
https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/terraform-cross-project-monitoring

```
locals {
  project_id           = "MY_MONITORING_PROJECT"
  metric_scopes = toset([
    "MY_MONITORED_PROJECT_1",
    "MY_MONITORED_PROJECT_2",
    "MY_MONITORED_PROJECT_3"
  ]) # List of projects included in metric scopes for MY_MONITORING_PROJECT.
}

resource "google_monitoring_monitored_project" "projects_monitored" {
  #provider      = google-beta # for versions before 4.2.0
  for_each      = local.metric_scopes
  metrics_scope = join("", ["locations/global/metricsScopes/", local.project_id])
  name          = each.value
}
```

You need at least `roles/monitoring.metricsScopesAdmin` or `roles/monitoring.admin` on each of the monitored projects to add them to scope.

There's an [bug](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/15625) in provider 4.77 that prevents adding projects with names that are different from their project_id leading to a 403 error. As a workaround, you can add projects to the scope before renaming if this is still an issue.